# Wet foundation on outside of house

Tags: wet

One corner on the outside of my house's foundation is always wet. Water seems to be running off that corner washing away dirt under the hot top and cracking the skim coat.
There are new gutters but no downspout on that side of the house. How can I find out why this is?
Thanks

Comment: Always wet and running makes me think of a leaking pipe.  Rain and a roof leak, it should dry up without rain.  Might just be a pinhole leak instead of a gusher.

Comment: You've only asked one question here: "how can I find out why this is?". I have a feeling though, that this isn't really the question you're looking for an answer to. Since we do work on a one question per post basis (take the [tour]), I've answered that question. Please feel free to [ask a whole new question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) about whatever else it is that's on your mind...

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question that was asked:

> There are new gutters but no downspout on that side of the house. How can I find out why this is?

Take a close look at the gutters. If they slope *away* from the corner in question, then the water in the gutters will flow away from the corner toward another downspout somewhere else. That would be why there is no gutter at this corner.

If the gutters slope *toward* this corner, then either they weren't installed properly (and should slope away), or someone messed up and forgot to install the down spouts.